# Azure Storage Rest API Authentication Header for Java Android

Tags: java, android, azure, rest, authentication

I'm working on an Android project downloading an image from Azure Blob storage and am getting response code 400 Authorization Header not valid.

```
URL url = new URL(src);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                Date date = new Date();
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","SAS Signature here?");
                connection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-date", date.toString());
                connection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2021-02-12");
                connection.connect();
                int response = connection.getResponseCode();
                Log.e("Response Code:",String.valueOf(response));
                Log.e("Response Message:",connection.getResponseMessage());
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a SAS token, you really do not have to do any of the things you are doing because SAS token has all the necessary authorization information. All you have to do is use the SAS URL (blob endpoint + SAS token) to create the connection and you should be able to download the blob.

Something like:

```
URL url = new URL(src);//src would be something like https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob.bmp?sastoken
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
int response = connection.getResponseCode();
Log.e("Response Code:",String.valueOf(response));
Log.e("Response Message:",connection.getResponseMessage());
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
```